# MySQL Stored procedure SELECT, three WHERE CLAUSE values and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

My stored function doesn't seem to be working I get a return of 10 rows of NULL and 40 warnings.

I would like to write a stored function that returns the highest paid for customer_id X between a start date D1 and an end date D2.

The table is structured as follows:

`sales(customer_id CHAR(1), date DATE, paid INT)`

Example row:

```
sales(A, 2014-12-20, 3456)
```

My stored function:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION highest_monthly_paid(x CHAR(1), D1 DATE, D2 DATE) 
      RETURNS INT
      DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE highest_fee INT;

        SELECT paid INTO highest_fee
        FROM sales
        WHERE customer_id = x 
        AND date > D1
        AND date < D2
        ORDER BY paid DESC LIMIT 1;
        RETURN highest_fee;
    END
    $$
```

Will this not work or am I better off using a subquery of some sort? and if both methods work which should I use?

I have tried `MAX(paid)` instead of `LIMIT`.

My query for calling the function:

```
SELECT highest_monthly_paid(A,  2013-12-10,  2013-12-25)
FROM sales;
```

There is two rows in the database with the customer_id of A:

```
+-------------+-------+----------+------------+--------+
| customer_id | model | quantity | day        | paid   |
+-------------+-------+----------+------------+--------+
| A           | 2002  |        2 | 2013-12-19 |   1898 |
| A           | 3002  |        1 | 2013-12-18 |    239 |
+-------------+-------+----------+------------+--------+
```

My result:

```
mysql> SELECT highest_monthly_paid(A,  2013-12-10,  2013-12-25)
    -> FROM sales;
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| highest_monthly_paid(A,  2013-12-10,  2013-12-25) |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
|                                                       NULL |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set, 30 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What are the warnings?

Comment: your function is not deterministic and I'm sure your customer_id isn't of the type `CHAR(1)`. If it should be you can't have many customers ... The best data type for fees is `DECIMAL`, not INT.

Comment: Generally speaking customer_id probably shouldn't be `CHAR(1)` and paid shouldn't be `INT` but unfortunately for this table they are. Should it be not deterministic? It only produces the one result? I am confused or misunderstand.

Comment: Look at changing `SELECT paid` with a limit to a `SELECT Max(Paid)` instead without the limit, to start. It's difficult to tell you why it isn't working with no sample data and desired output and no clear description of the data types involved, as well as no indication of how you're calling the function.

Comment: @aazzaawwaazzaa how many different values can CHAR(1) have? And no, your function is not deterministic. The result depends of the values in your table.

Comment: If the `char(1)` field is a proper unicode field, then it should be able to contain as many different values as there are different unicode characters, which is over 1.1 million. But still not very usable and readable. Generally INT is better for IDs

Comment: @GolezTrol you're right, it can use w Bytes - not one as I assumed.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! I have added more information as suggested.

Comment: @VMai I have now changed the function to `NOT DETERMINISTIC` and I am down to 20 warnings. :)

Comment: `2013-12-10` is not a date, it's a number: `2013 minus 12 minus 10` if you want MySQL to recognize it as a date put it in single quotes: `'2013-12-10'`

Comment: that accounts for 20 warnings in 10 rows. @aazzaawwaazzaa your function call should not have a FROM clause. It returns a value for each row of the referenced table else.

Comment: @VMai Again thank you, that is it! Something so small. Only other thing is there is still 10 rows in the result which are all of the same value of course but is there a reason why?

Comment: Use your function simply with `SELECT highest_monthly_paid('A',  '2013-12-10',  '2013-12-25');`. Don't add a `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think following query should be sufficient to fetch the highest_fee for each customer for a given date range. Please let us know if you have some other requirements.

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(paid) AS highest_fees
FROM sales
WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-12-10' AND '2013-12-25'
GROUP BY customer_id
```